# MQ Channel restart from code giving error

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have written some Java code to start and stop an MQ channel. I have created a Server-connection channel on MQ for testing this code. But while executing the Java code, both start and stop of the channel gives errors.

**Stop Channel gives the below error:**

```
about to stop channel
MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2202
```

**Start Channel gives the following error:**

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009
```

**Code:**

```
package com.asm.MQListenerChannelRestart;

import com.ibm.mq.pcf.*;
import com.ibm.mq.*;
import com.ibm.mq.pcf.CMQCFC;


public class MQListenerChannelRestart implements CMQCFC  {

    public void startChannel(PCFAgent pcfAgent){
        PCFParameter [] parameters = new PCFParameter [] {
                new MQCFST (MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "TESTChanne"),
                new MQCFST(MQCACH_USER_ID,"user"),
                new MQCFST(MQCACH_PASSWORD,"password")
             };


        try {

            System.out.println("about to start channel");
            MQMessage [] pcfResponses = pcfAgent.send (MQCMD_START_CHANNEL, 
                                                  parameters);

            MQCFH cfh = new MQCFH(pcfResponses[0]);
            System.out.println("Parameter count="+cfh.parameterCount);
            System.out.println("Reason = "+cfh.reason);
            System.out.println(cfh.toString());

            pcfResponses = pcfAgent.send(MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS, parameters);
            cfh = new MQCFH(pcfResponses[0]);
            System.out.println("Channel status is ==="+cfh.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopChannel(PCFAgent pcfAgent){
        PCFParameter [] parameters = new PCFParameter [] {
                new MQCFST (MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "TESTChanne"),
                new MQCFIN (MQIACF_QUIESCE, MQQO_NO )
               };


        try {

            System.out.println("about to stop channel");
            MQMessage [] pcfResponses = pcfAgent.send (MQCMD_STOP_CHANNEL, 
                                                  parameters);

            MQCFH cfh = new MQCFH(pcfResponses[0]);
            System.out.println("Parameter count="+cfh.parameterCount);
            System.out.println("Reason = "+cfh.reason);
            System.out.println(cfh.toString());

            pcfResponses = pcfAgent.send(MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS, parameters);
            cfh = new MQCFH(pcfResponses[0]);
            System.out.println("Channel status is ==="+cfh.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PCFAgent pcfAgent = null;


        MQListenerChannelRestart mqListenerChannelRestart = new MQListenerChannelRestart();
        mqListenerChannelRestart.stopChannel(pcfAgent);
        mqListenerChannelRestart.startChannel(pcfAgent);
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: Please give the full snippet, specifically the code where the pcfAgent object is created.

Comment: I have now provided the entire code...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you never actually instantiated your PCFAgent object.

Secondly, you send the PCF command to the queue manager via a PCFMessageAgent. PCFMessageAgent actually extends PCFAgent, so create an object of PCFMessageAgent.

Thirdly, I don't think the response coming from a PCFCommand can be held in an MQMessage, rather it shoud be taken in a PCFMessage.

What you should do is read more about PCF [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zr00120_.htm)

Also here is a very good example of PCF_CommonMethods here: ftp:// 119.44.222.58/opt/mqm/samp/pcf/samples/PCF_CommonMethods.java

As of now you would like to code something like below:

```
 PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent ("localhost", 1414, "CLIENT");
 PCFParameter [] parameters = new PCFParameter [] {
            new MQCFST (MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "TESTChanne"),
            new MQCFST(MQCACH_USER_ID,"user"),
            new MQCFST(MQCACH_PASSWORD,"password")
         };

       PCFMessage   request = new PCFMessage (MQCMD_START_CHANNEL,parameters);

       PCFMessage []   responses = agent.send (request);
```